# How to disable synthesized bold and italic algorithm in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts

I have been working on application that use Qt+qml for UI and PoDoFo to generate PDF file. All features that I need work good except text rendering. PoDoFo use exist fonts and fonts style but Qt synthesized bold, italic style and convert not regular style to regular if font file with such styles are absent. For example if I have on Windows "GenevaSF Thin" PoDoFo rendering this fonts as Thin but Qt render it like Regular with font weight 400. Other case If I set bold and italic flag in QFont object and font style "Bold Italic" is absent, Qt atomically take bold and apply "italic" matrix to generate Italic style.

In Qt source code I found **QWindowsFontEngine** class that contains method

```
int QWindowsFontEngine::synthesized() const
{
    if(synthesized_flags == -1) {
        synthesized_flags = 0;
        if(ttf) {
            const DWORD HEAD = MAKE_TAG('h', 'e', 'a', 'd');
            HDC hdc = m_fontEngineData->hdc;
            SelectObject(hdc, hfont);
            uchar data[4];
            GetFontData(hdc, HEAD, 44, &data, 4);
            USHORT macStyle = getUShort(data);
            if (tm.tmItalic && !(macStyle & 2))
                synthesized_flags = SynthesizedItalic;
            if (fontDef.stretch != 100 && ttf)
                synthesized_flags |= SynthesizedStretch;
            if (tm.tmWeight >= 500 && !(macStyle & 1))
                synthesized_flags |= SynthesizedBold;
            //qDebug() << "font is" << _name <<
            //    "it=" << (macStyle & 2) << fontDef.style << "flags=" << synthesized_flags;
        }
    }
    return synthesized_flags;
}
```

But I don't know how to disable synthesized_flags flags.

**Examples:**

I installed "Geneva SF Light", "Geneva SF ExtraBold", "Geneva SF Light Italic" fonts on windows and create font using next code:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily("Geneva SF");
font.setPointSize(20);
```

In this case Qt use "Geneva SF Light" .ttf file but atomically change font 'weight' from QFont::Light to QFont::Normal, but I need font with QFont::Light weight.

Other case. I create bold font:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily("Geneva SF");
font.setPointSize(20);
font.setBold(true);
```

In this case Qt use "Geneva SF ExtraBold" .ttf file but atomically change font 'weight' from QFont::ExtraBold to QFont::Bold, but I need font with QFont::ExtraBold weight.

Example with "Bold Italic" style:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily("Geneva SF");
font.setPointSize(20);
font.setBold(true);
font.setItalic(true);
```

In this case Qt use "Geneva SF ExtraBold" .ttf file but atomically change font 'weight' from QFont::ExtraBold to QFont::Bold and apply transformation matrix that change font angle, but I need non italic font with QFont::ExtraBold.

Maybe possible get weight from .ttf file that QFont use.

Comment: can you show an [mcve](/help/mcve) that demonstrates how you're currently loading and then using a normal weight, as well as a custom weight font? We'll mostly be guessing without that information, and questions that require guess work tend to get passed over in favour of [better explained questions](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sounds like you might be experiencing a bug like this one: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46042. That's referring to FreeType on Linux specifically, but I imagine similar problems existing on Windows.